# Dealing with GET char limit

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, get

I have a .js script that sends data to a .py script running on the local host.

To send data from the .js, I have the following work around (to deal with the limitations of XmlHTTPRequest):

```
var req = document.createElement("img");
req.src = "http://0.0.0.0:8000?var="+data
```

To recieve it on the python end:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

conn, addr = s.accept()
data = conn.recv(1024)
conn.close()

print data
```

This works fine, but my problem is that the char limit on a GET prevents me from sending all of the data I need.  I tried making to URI GET requests (using the first block of code twice), but my python only recieved the first request.  How can I send/recieve mulitple GET requests?  I am assuming I will need some sort of loop, but am unsure what steps need to be in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Python code, it doesn't seem like the HTTP request method used makes any difference. In that case, I'd recommend setting up a form element with `method="post"` and just putting whatever you want in it. There's no theoretical limit on post body length.